# Issues on Windows high contrast mode

Tags: foxit-reader

I have win11, and I'm using a high contrast theme.

Dialogs, such as Preferences or About, have a white text on a white background.

I posted this issue somewhere five years ago.

[image]

Comment: This likely comes down to Foxit Reader not correctly using the Windows UI APIs. I doubt there's a tweak that will fix this. You would need to report the issue to Foxit and hope they correct their code to integrate with the OS correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using "Use windows color scheme" ?

Comment: Funny, it's the first option in my screenshot, which is currently selected, but you can't read it.